# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mci\admin\model.php on line 21

Tags: php, mysql, tags

help me.. i get error

after input in mysql to two query function
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mci\admin\model.php on line 21

```html
<?php
session_start();
include "../koneksidb/koneksidb.php";
$module = isset($_GET['module']);
$act = isset($_GET['act']);


if ($module=='masterpc' AND $act=='input')
 (
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO masterpc(hostname,os,ip,user,section,location,keyos,keydown,keyoffice,datecreate,cH9,cH10,cH11,cH12) 
  VALUES('$_POST[host]',
    '$_POST[os]',
    '$_POST[ip]',
    '$_POST[user]',
    '$_POST[section]',
    '$_POST[location]',
    '$_POST[keyw1]-$_POST[keyw2]-$_POST[keyw3]-$_POST[keyw4]-$_POST[keyw5]',
    '$_POST[keyd1]-$_POST[keyd2]-$_POST[keyd3]-$_POST[keyd4]-$_POST[keyd5]',
    '$_POST[keyof1]-$_POST[keyof2]-$_POST[keyof3]-$_POST[keyof4]-$_POST[keyof5]',
    'NOW()','','','','')")
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO iphistory(ip,hostname,datecreate)
  VALUES('$_POST[ip]',
      '$_POST[host]',  
    'NOW()' 
    )");
 ) 
 


 
 ?>
```

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mci\admin\model.php on line 21
```

Comment: You are still using MySQL_* extension. Why?

Comment: if i do one mysql_query the data success input to database

Answer (score 1):

After `if` condition second bracket `{}` is required not first bracket. eg, `if($con){....}` not `if($con)(....)`. Also there lack of `;` after first query. Try this...

```
if ($module=='masterpc' AND $act=='input')
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO masterpc(hostname,os,ip,user,section,location,keyos,keydown,keyoffice,datecreate,cH9,cH10,cH11,cH12) 
    VALUES('$_POST[host]',
            '$_POST[os]',
            '$_POST[ip]',
            '$_POST[user]',
            '$_POST[section]',
            '$_POST[location]',
            '$_POST[keyw1]-$_POST[keyw2]-$_POST[keyw3]-$_POST[keyw4]-$_POST[keyw5]',
            '$_POST[keyd1]-$_POST[keyd2]-$_POST[keyd3]-$_POST[keyd4]-$_POST[keyd5]',
            '$_POST[keyof1]-$_POST[keyof2]-$_POST[keyof3]-$_POST[keyof4]-$_POST[keyof5]',
            'NOW()','','','','')");
                                 ^^^
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO iphistory(ip,hostname,datecreate)
    VALUES('$_POST[ip]',
           '$_POST[host]',      
            'NOW()' 
            )");
 }
```

Comment: wass succesfull... thaks very much Sir :D

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are denoted with braces (`{ ... }`), not parens (`( ... )`).

```
if (...)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: id do it.. still error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mci\admin\model.php on line 21

Comment: wass succesfull... thaks very much Sir :D

Answer (score 0):

the form post

```html
<html>

<h2>Input Master PC</h2>
<form id=validasi method=POST action='model.php?module=masterpc&act=input'>
<table>
<tr><td>HOST NAME</td>
<td> : <input type=text name=host maxlength=12  size=13 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <?php
  include('componentdata/data_host.php');
  ?>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>OS</td>
<td> : <input type=text name=os class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <?php
  include('componentdata/data_os.php');
  ?>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>IP</td>
<td> : <input type=text name=ip maxlength=15 size=30 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <?php
  include('componentdata/data_ip.php');
  ?>

</td></tr>
<tr><td>USER</td>
<td> : <input type=text name=user size=40 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  
</td></tr>

<tr><td>Section</td>
<td> : <input type=text name=section size=60 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <?php
  include('componentdata/data_section.php');
  ?>

</td></tr>
<tr><td>Location</td>
<td> : <input type=text name=location size=40 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Product Key Windows</td>
<td> : <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyw1 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyw2 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyw3 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyw4 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyw5 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>

</td></tr>
<tr><td>Product Key Downgrade</td>
<td> : <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyd1 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyd2 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyd3 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyd4 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyd5 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>

</td></tr>
<tr><td>Product Key Office</td>
<td> : <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyof1 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyof2 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyof3 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyof4 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>
  <input type=text maxlength=5 name=keyof5 size=6 class='required' title='nama Kelas harus diisi !'>

</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2><input type=submit value=Simpan>
<input type=button value=Batal onclick=self.history.back()>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>

</html>
```